# Objective C and ARC

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

First, I am new to Objective C and I read some on internet. On iOS and on MAC can I use ARC without any memory management knowledge like release, retain, autorelease etc. On some places it says on MAC I can use ARC but on iOS I need to do manual management, on some places it says I can use ARC on iOS but I need to do some manual management. So what is correct answer?

Comment: you can use ARC on iOS. you shouldnt need any prior knowledge about releasing and retaining etc, but it will help to know about it

Comment: So I do not need to know any memory management when I use ARC right? And Can you tell me what is strong, weak, copy?

Comment: yeah arc will take care of memory management for you. strong/weak in short is: when all strong references to an object are gone (set to nil) then an object will be deleted, even if there are still weak references pointing to that object. an object will only exist if it has at least 1 strong reference to it. afaik the default is strong if not specified

Comment: `A owns B` means `A` has a strong reference to `B`, and `B` *may* have a weak reference to `A`.

Comment: can we say that:       object a has object b.  so when we implement will we write  @property (strong) OBJ *objecta;     ?     when should I use (strong, weak, copy, assign) ?

Answer (score 2):

> ARC is supported in Xcode 4.2 for OS X v10.6 and v10.7 (64-bit applications) and for iOS 4 and iOS 5. Weak references are not supported in OS X v10.6 and iOS 4.

Source: [Transitioning to ARC release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)